# Symfony2 : Change locale Slug multi-langue

Tags: php, symfony, twig, slug

I'm trying to create my web multi-language application, i want to change the default locale with compatibility of slug, because my slug are also multi-langue.

I'm using JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle() to change the locale.

and on my twig views i have :

```html
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_locale') == 'fr' %}
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge(app.request.query.all|merge({'_locale': 'en' }))) }}">
            en
        </a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')|merge(app.request.query.all|merge({'_locale': 'fr' }))) }}">
            fr
        </a>
    {% endif %}
```

The problem now is :
 - when i set the locale to Fr for example, i get all my entities from database in case of the current locale, for now is beautiful, when i access to a page for example, with the slug imported from database, and i try to change the locale to en, the problem is, on my views nothing changed from database, but the translation set in the files i18n are imported.

What can i do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

By treating data from your database like any other string which needs to be translated:

[Translation Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html)

In your Controllers, this would look something like:

```
$translated = $this->get('translator')->trans( $row['field'] );
```

In your Templates, it would look something like:

```
{{ field|trans }}
```

Now all you need to do is provide translations for every possible 'key' that could come out of your database.  Hopefully, you're NOT trying to translate data entered by a French user automatically into English on output - this is NOT the job of the Translator Component - leave that up to Google Translate.